# Apply CultureInfo binding to column DataGrid in c#

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I want to apply a thousand separators to the columns of Data Grid view in the following way but the same time I want to apply CultureInfo "de-DE" to the binding. How can I set `CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de-DE")` to following statement.

```
private void preview_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
    {                
        DataGridTextColumn col = e.Column as DataGridTextColumn;
        if (col != null && e.PropertyType == typeof(decimal) || e.PropertyType == typeof(double) || e.PropertyType==typeof(float))
        {
           col.Binding = new Binding(e.PropertyName) { StringFormat = "{0:n}"};//here I want to use CultureInfo.
        }
     }
```

Comment: do you just want this column to be this culture, or whole control?

Comment: This column only!

Comment: if it is very difficult, what about define some another property which converts to some string in `get`, and bind then?

Comment: As I declared in If condition I just want to apply this culture to only those column which has numeric datatype.

Comment: what about considering other events, such as `CellFormating`

Comment: I am not using such event in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private void preview_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
    {                
        DataGridTextColumn col = e.Column as DataGridTextColumn;
        if (col != null && e.PropertyType == typeof(decimal) || e.PropertyType == typeof(double) || e.PropertyType==typeof(float))
        {
           col.Binding = new Binding(e.PropertyName) { StringFormat = "{0:n}", ConverterCulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de-DE")};//here I want to use CultureInfo.
        }
     }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question?

Comment: Please accept the answer and vote it up then: https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: maybe it's because he answered his own question?